# How to create a tensor with shape [null,256] in Tensorflow js?

Tags: tensorflow.js

I'm having problem in creating a latent point for my GAN model in Tensorflow js, my model keep spitting this error..

" Error when checking : expected input_4 to have shape [null,256] but got array with shape [8,1]"

How can I create a tensor with shape [null,256] in Tensorflow js ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you search for "null" in https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/ you'll see that null means any dimension. So a tensor with shape [1, 256] or [42, 256] or the like should work.

When I was first using TFJS I also was confused by "null". Perhaps the TFJS can put some effort into making error messages easier to understand???